# Meaning of the "雨菽" phrase in 明史

Tags: translation, classical-chinese

In the sentence below there are two phrases: "雨菽" and "兵端吐火". I am not sure if they should be read as a metaphor for hail (雨菽) and a rebellion/mutiny (兵端吐火)?

今春以來，天鼓兩震於晉地，流星晝隕於清豐，地震二十八，天火九，石首雨菽，河內女妖，遼東兵端吐火，即春秋二百四十年間，未有稠於今日者。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 今春以來，天鼓兩震於晉地，流星晝隕於清豐，地震二十八，天火九，石首雨菽，河內女妖，遼東兵端吐火，即春秋二百四十年間，未有稠於今日者

in 明史 列傳第一百四十五, under the entry of 熊明遇; mr 熊 submitted a memorial (上疏) to list current malpractice (極陳時弊), which contains the text:

https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=143005&page=53

“石首雨菽”, rough means:

[in the place] (石首), beans and peas rained (雨菽) [from the sky]

i would treat it as fact, it’s not that uncommon:

https://historyofyesterday.com/strange-things-that-rained-from-the-sky-throughout-history/

https://zippyfacts.com/where-did-food-fall-from-the-sky/

“遼東兵端吐火” roughly means:

[in] manchuria (遼東), there’re flame at the tip / point of weapons (兵端吐火)

weapons referred to swords, knifes, spears or halberds, etc . . .

also, i would treat it as fact, with two possible “scientific” explanations

- [st elmo’s fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Elmo%27s_fire)
- [will-o'-the-wisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will-o%27-the-wisp)

edited, photos added

[image]

https://atoptics.wordpress.com/tag/st-elmos-fire/

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

The said sentence is part of an article written by 熊明遇, purportedly in 萬曆四十三年. Therefore we look for events around that year, and see:

石首雨菽: 明史 卷二十九: 萬曆四十三年四月戊寅，石首雨豆，大小不一，色雜紅黑。

兵端: I haven't found a record of conflict around this year. [明史紀事本末補遺](https://tpl.ncl.edu.tw/NclService/pdfdownload?filePath=lV8OirTfsslWcCxIpLbUfhQHstx_oOBLmugX_OHwzV3sfVP2HMHzcN9uYfvD6C9Q&imgType=Bn5sH4BGpJw=&key=5Fa9x7S8tb5c9TqndF3qh6QVQJv7jjJCbV2p-wgLr3EeVVU9OyINO4qBZJhLTxWd&xmlId=0007204705) says: 五月，北關白羊骨以老女婚煖兔子莽骨兒大。建州兵三千屯南關，然恐撫
順、清河犄其後，按兵不動。

吐火: 明史 卷二十九: 萬曆[...]四十三年[...]遼東長寧堡自二月至五月，火凡五發，毀房屋人畜無算。